# Circuit Fails when wires capped but not when light is inline

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker

curious to hear your thoughts. It's on old 1960's house and I can't trace all the wiring. In the diagram: when the porcelain single bulb light is hooked-up the Black and dotted white wire, the light works and break is Not tripped. Also works fine whether switched off/on. When I cap those two wires together, the break trips to off position.
Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

The picture has the black & white wires in question, with red on them.
I wired in the light to the left and the run works fine...grr

Comment: Gonna need photos or a clearer description.  You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Why are you connecting the two wires together? Clearly that's causing a short and tripping the breaker.  A much better circuit drawing and more revealing photos would help.

Answer (score 1):

#### A Simple Short Circuit

**when the porcelain single bulb light is hooked-up the Black and dotted white wire, the light works and break is Not tripped. Also works fine whether switched off/on. When I cap those two wires together, the break trips to off position.**

- Black wire going to bulb is "hot"
- White wire going to bulb is "neutral"

A circuit is panel -> "hot" -> load (e.g., light) -> "neutral" -> panel.

When you cap the two wires together *without any load between them*, you let **ALL** the possible electricity flow through. Otherwise known as a "short circuit". The breaker then trips, **as it is designed to do** to protect your wiring and prevent your house from burning down.